# Formatting SQL Server Query for color coded table in HTML output

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

I'm coding a SQL Server query that queries hard drive information from a series of computers and highlights the drives with less than 20% capacity. I'd like to make the ones with 10% or less capacity yellow. I'm using a case statement in my query and I'm having trouble with the syntax.

```
CASE 
   WHEN ((UsedSpace/CAST(TotalSpace as decimal(18,2))) > 0.9) 
      THEN CAST('''<font color="yellow">'' + [FreeSpace] + ''</font>''' AS varchar(150)) 
      ELSE [FreeSpace] 
END AS 'td',
```

This causes an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''' + [FreeSpace] + ''' to data type int.

Comment: This like means that the output of the CASE expression is an integer value.  You've got a CASE condition that returns CHAR data instead.    Make sure each WHEN clause returns Character data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing data types... INT and Strings

Assuming you are creating and HTML Table,  one option is to use `concat()` and XML.  `concat()` is an easy way to mix data types without having to be concerned with conversions.

**Example**

```
Declare @yourtable table (UsedSpace int,TotalSpace int,FreeSpace int)
Insert into @YourTable values 
 ( 95,100,5)
,( 80,100,20)

Select 

 CASE WHEN ((UsedSpace/CAST(TotalSpace as decimal(18,2))) > 0.9) 
      THEN convert(XML,concat('<font color="yellow">',[FreeSpace],'</font>'))
      ELSE concat('',FreeSpace) END as 'td'
 From @YourTable
 For XML Path('tr')
```

**Results**

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <font color="yellow">5</font>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @alcor8 Always happy to help